# LoadError when installing ruby devkit

Tags: ruby, init

I have installed ruby on Windows 7 using the installer `Ruby 1.9.3-p125` which is the latest version (`ruby -v` shows the right version). Next, I downloaded `devkit-3.4.5r3-20091110`, which is also the latest version.  When I tried the following in the installation directory,

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

the console showed an error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- dk.rb (LoadError)
```

I am new to ruby and I don't want to learn ruby — I just want to use [Jekyll](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html) which needs ruby.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: type: dir, hit enter and add the output to the end of your question.

Comment: Did you extract the devkit installation files?

Comment: oh,god! I should download devkit 4.5.2!

Answer (score 5):

Try to run the command from the devkit folder, and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I "cd" into devkit folder, it work well.

Comment: i dont have a devkit folder, although I did select devkit when installing

Comment: @Andrew Ruby 2.4 onwards it is msys2 and devkit is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the dev kit from [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). You'll find `dk.rb` in the directory you extracted the contents to.