# Ruby Install/Init Not Finding dk.rb

Tags: ruby, installation, init

I'm trying to download/install Ruby on Win7(I'm new to Ruby).

I went to this url: 
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and downloaded version "Ruby 1.9.3-p545"  I installed into the following folder/directory: C:\RubyDevKit\ (no spaces in folder name).

I'm getting the following error when I try to do the init step:

```
C:\RubyDevKit>ruby dk.rb init
ruby: No such file or directory -- dk.rb (LoadError)
```

I ran this on the command line:

```
C:\RubyDevKit>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

So I do have ruby installed and I'm in the correct directory(per this SO link:[LoadError when installing ruby devkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748107/loaderror-when-installing-ruby-devkit))

I also tried and got the same error:

```
C:\RubyDevKit>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252
```

I do have Aptana v3, build 3.4.2.201308081805 installed(but no other versions of Ruby).  I also can't find the acutal file dk.rb anywhere through windows explorer/cmd line.

```
C:\RubyDevKit>dir
Volume in drive C is Local Disk
Volume Serial Number is 0CBF-3D16

Directory of C:\RubyDevKit

05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          .
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          bin
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          doc
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          include
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          lib
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          share
05/29/2014  03:04 PM           167,349 unins000.dat
05/29/2014  03:04 PM         1,193,995 unins000.exe
           2 File(s)      1,361,344 bytes
           7 Dir(s)  1,287,681,196,032 bytes free
```

The bin directory:

```
C:\RubyDevKit>cd bin

C:\RubyDevKit\bin>dir
Volume in drive C is Local Disk
Volume Serial Number is 0CBF-3D16

Directory of C:\RubyDevKit\bin

05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          .
05/29/2014  03:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/24/2014  09:20 PM             4,397 erb
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 erb.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               921 gem
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 gem.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               318 irb
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 irb.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM         1,486,336 libeay32.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM           127,316 libffi-6.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM           140,586 libgdbm-3.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM           103,726 libgdbm_compat-3.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM         1,262,898 libiconv-2.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM           441,874 libyaml-0-2.dll
02/24/2014  09:17 PM         2,289,664 msvcrt-ruby191.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM           238,505 pdcurses.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM             1,231 rake
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 rake.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               788 rdoc
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 rdoc.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               188 ri
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 ri.bat
02/24/2014  09:17 PM            70,239 ruby.exe
02/24/2014  09:17 PM            70,239 rubyw.exe
12/30/2013  01:11 PM               312 setrbvars.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM           341,504 ssleay32.dll
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               298 testrb
02/24/2014  09:20 PM               177 testrb.bat
02/24/2014  09:20 PM            83,968 zlib1.dll
          27 File(s)      6,666,547 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  1,287,679,569,920 bytes free
```

I'm not sure what to do to get Ruby up and running, specifically getting past the "init" step.

**Edit**:
In the Aptana IDE -> Terminal I typed:

```
$ gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby
```

and got back:

```
Fetching: ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
    The 'ruby-debug-ide' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Also to add(from the cmd line:

```
C:\RubyDevKit\bin>gem -v
1.8.28
```

Comment: are you sure you need to run the dk.rb? your ruby seems to be working already. http://railsinstaller.org/ might work better, just ignore the rails stuff.

Comment: How do I tell if Ruby is working/installed correctly?

Comment: `ruby -v` runs so it's probably working. if `gem -v` works too, you're good to go.

Comment: I am getting something back(I updated the original answer a bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need DEVKIT to build native C extensions.

In your case it does not sound like you have downloaded the DEVKIT separately.
Secondly ensure that the DEVKIT and Ruby are matching architecturally, as well as that of the system you are running on (x86/64).

Consider the following tutorial:
http://www.waydotnet.com/2010/02/12/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/

Comment: This is where I went to download/install Ruby: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/  Is this correct, or is the devkit something else that I need to download/install?

Comment: Yes that is correct. A little further down on that page is the DevKit, that needs to be installed.

Comment: I've not watched it - but this may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bnav4Hw7NdY

Comment: I've downloaded the DevKit, reinstalled aptana, is there something I can do to show that everything is ok?

Comment: As you did previously - test gem install in command line. Ensure DevKit path set.

Comment: Adding the DevKit helped, also I had to update the PATH manually for some reason, but then everything worked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DaneBalia This didn't work for me, I had already installed the DevKit with matching version/architecture  (tdm54-gcc-4.9.2-3.exe) and there's no dk.rb file in the install directory...

Answer (score 2):

In case other people have this problem the real answer is that the latest version of the DevKit does not have a file called dk.rb. Only the older version DevKit 4.5 (DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) which is for use with Ruby 1.9.3-p551 uses the dr.rb configuration script.

TL;DR: If are following a tutorial that mentions dk.rb the simplest thing to do is to use Ruby 1.9 and DevKit 4.5

Comment: BUSTED ! sdk "WITH DEVKIT" does not contain devkit